# Get all rows of specific class type into List

Tags: c#, list, entity-framework

I have class

```
public class testClass
{
    public int testClassID { get; set; }
    public int param1ID { get; set; }
    public int param2ID{ get; set; }
}
```

Then in controller I want to find all rows and put them into list but use specific param during find

```
List<testClass> Rows = _context.testClasses.Find(u => u.param2ID== param2ID).ToList();
```

After writing this I get error

> cannot convert lambda expression of type 'object' because it's not a
>   delegate type

Comment: If that's [this Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.find?view=efcore-3.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContext_Find_System_Type_System_Object___) then it expects a `params object[]` but you're passing a lambda to it, thus the error.

Comment: How are `testClasses` defined?

Comment: `.Find()` only returns one element, use `.FindAll()` or `.Where()`

Comment: Welcome to strong typed programming language ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probalby mean Where:

```
List<testClass> Rows = _context.testClasses.Where(u => u.param2ID == param2ID).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Find method returns an object and cannot be converted to List.
This is what you need:

```
List<testClass> Rows = _context.testClasses.Where(u => u.param2ID == param2ID).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
List<testClass> _resp = _context.testClasses.Where(u => u.param2ID == u.param2ID).ToList();
```